# vb6: set SysTabControl32 by code

Tags: api, vb6, sendmessage

i'm coding a little app for controlling soulseek - what i want do is clicking the "Search Files" button by code.

i've got the handle to the tabbed control (SysTabControl32) and managed to change the tab
with following code:

```
rc1 = SendMessage(hwnd, TCM_SETCURFOCUS, ByVal 0, ByVal 0&)
```

the problem:

the tab control is changing to the proper button, but nothing happens.
i assume i also also have to send a mouseclick to it, as when clicking by mouse, the button goes down and up again.

any ideas how to do this?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Use [TCM_SETCURSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760612(VS.85).aspx) instead.

```
Private Const TCM_FIRST               As Long = &H1300
Private Const TCM_SETCURSEL           As Long = (TCM_FIRST + 12)
```